# Why ENLIST=TRUE is increase count of sessions of oracle for the max?

Tags: wcf, msdtc

We are using MSDTC in WCF service. Configuration consist of 3 computers:
1. Server Oracle on Linux.
2. IIS with client of service WCF on server 2003.
3. IIS with server of service WCF and server Oracle on server 2003.

If connection string has property ENLIST=FALSE the service is work! But distributed transactions work correctly not always. Sometimes one side(client service) is commit, other side(server service) is not commit.

If connection string has property ENLIST=TRUE the service is work! But count of sessions of oracle is increase for the max and service didn't work.

Can anyone tell me why sessions is increase when ENLIST=TRUE ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved. Two clients is installed on mashine with IIS, and application work with one client, msdtc is supported by other client. After remove both clients and install one client application worked successfull!!!